# I cannot understand this typedef

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code:

```
typedef struct _tagCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT
{
  HWND  hWndClient;
  BOOL  bExitLoop;
  LONG  lSleepTimeout;
} COMMUNICATIONOBJECT, *PCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT;
```

The way I understand this is _tagCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT is the structure that has 3 public members hWndClient, …
My question: what are COMMUNICATIONOBJECT and *PCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT? I am not familiar with this syntax.

Thank you!

Jules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the old way Microsoft defined most of their structures. It works in C and C++. In C++ just the name after the `struct` keyword would be enough as it auto-typedef's such a name.

But to make it clearer you could re-write such as follow:

```
struct _tagCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT
{
  HWND  hWndClient;
  BOOL  bExitLoop;
  LONG  lSleepTimeout;
};

typedef struct _tagCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT COMMUNICATIONOBJECT;
typedef struct _tagCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT *PCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT;
```

So in C++ they define 3 names:

```
_tagCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT
COMMUNICATIONOBJECT
PCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT
```

Answer (score 0):

`COMMUNICATIONOBJECT` is the name of the typedef and `PCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT` is a pointer to such a typedef.

Answer (score 0):

By putting `typedef` before `struct`, you can define the struct and then list new aliases for it after the definition. `COMMUNICATIONOBJECT` is a new name for `_tagCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT` and `PCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT` is a new name for a pointer to the struct. It could be written like this instead:

```
struct _tagCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT
{
    HWND  hWndClient;
    BOOL  bExitLoop;
    LONG  lSleepTimeout;
};
typedef _tagCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT COMMUNICATIONOBJECT;
typedef _tagCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT *PCOMMUNICATIONOBJECT;
```